# Bootstrap auto generate <p> tag in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

Can anyone help me with this?, I use `the_content()` in my p tag and the bootstrap auto generate more `p` tag, and even the content did not placed inside the `p`. it is inside another `p`

picture-1:
[image]

picture-2:
[image]

Comment: Please add your code instead of the pictures to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the_content() will always wrap the content with a `<p>` tag.

You can use get_the_content() insted of the_content() but using get_the_content() will give you the content without any shortcodes or embedded media as mentioned at [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/).

This is another solution to get exactly what you want:

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$replace = '<p class="discription">';
echo str_replace('<p>', $replace, $content ); ?>
```